# Add a drop shadow to transparent text with CSS

Tags: css

Is there a way to add a **drop shadow** to transparent text so the background behind the text remains visible? Maybe some way to use the text itself as a mask? Or a text-blend-mode (with reasonable cross-browser support)?

My naive attempt:

```css
span {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/EWDVnfb.png);
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 100pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: .5em;
    text-shadow: 0 0 .5em #F00;
}
```

```html
<span>Test</span>
```

Comment: `color: transparent` will not work because ["Unlike box-shadow, text shadows are not clipped to the shadowed shape and may show through if the text is partially-transparent."](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-shadow-property)

Comment: I [kind of solved it,](http://jsfiddle.net/x7y80b74/), but I feel it is way too hacky to post as an answer. It should work for webkit browsers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution that works on Chrome and Safari:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvb8t1Lo/13/)

Basically, the idea is to have 2 `div` overplayed on each other. The lower one provides the background and the shadow. And the the div above just uses a mask to cut out the exact same text from the background image, so that it covers the text of lower element, but not the shadow:

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/EWDVnfb.png);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 100pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: .5em;
}
div.shadow {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 .5em #F00;
}
div.text {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

**EDIT**

I just found a [wonderful article on css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) So, there seems to be a solution with much better browser support. The idea is to replace the top-layer div by and svg containing the same text and use a pattern to fill the text with the background image, here's a sketch:

```
<div class="shadow">Test</div>
<div>
    <svg width="400" height="200">
        <pattern id="mask" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
             width="400" height="200" viewbox="0 0 400 200">
            <image xlink:href="..." width="300" height="300" />
        </pattern>
        <text x="0" y="1em">Test</text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS (in addition to the CSS of my above solution):

```
text {
  fill:url(#mask);
}
```

I've been trying to get this to work as well, with partial success. ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nvb8t1Lo/16/)) But I'm not very good with svg's and someone else might be able to fix it. Anyway, the weakness here is that positioning this correctly and reliably is a real pain while you get that automagically right with the Webkit-only solution.

Comment: Note that this is proprietary to WebKit and not implemented elsewhere. `-webkit-text-fill-color` appears to be an internal replacement for `color`, and the `text` value for `background-clip` does not appear in either Backgrounds 3 or 4 - presumably because it doesn't really make sense when it's the *foreground* text you're styling, not background.