# Transparent letter/text with solid outline - Internet Explorer / CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I currently have the following code to make the big H appear as shown in the image (transparent with border):

[image: transparent H]

CSS

```
.shadow-H {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 75px;
}

@supports((text-stroke: 1px white) or (-webkit-text-stroke: 1px white)) {
  .shadow-H {
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
    text-stroke: 1px white;
    text-shadow: none;
   }
}
```

I am very much struggling with getting an equivalent style to work in IE (10 or above). I am able to get the H to have a solid fill color and outline in Internet Explorer, but can't get that solid fill color to be transparent or only adjust the opacity of the fill.

I've done a lot of searches to try and find something, but haven't had any success yet. Thanks!

Comment: Try adding `filter: alpha(opacity=50);`

Comment: I have tried this as well, but it does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Why not just use a svg image?

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750372/add-a-drop-shadow-to-transparent-text-with-css

Comment: Thanks! Going to give an SVG a try.