# Stroke-color when using mix-blend-mode screen

Tags: html, css

I have a text where i only want to show the outer edge as a stroke.
Furthermore, this stroke should have an outer glow / text shadow.

I am almost there, but one of my colors is messing up. I guess that is because it is blending with the background color.

I want it to look like this. Please note the color of the word "Cyber" (`#ffcd00`).

[image]

This is how it looks at the moment.
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wcu2ba5d/1/)

Please ignore the background image and the different font used in the fiddle. It's only the color of the word "cyber" i want to fix.

In the fiddle is has a color close to `#e6d5a6`, but it should be close to `#ffcd00`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT I have been unable to find a way of adding the shadow to Cyber using mix-blend-mode in a way that keeps its brightness. The shadow gets mixed with the blueish background which makes the orangey color look dull. The method works with Monday because the blueish colors are similar.

Here is a way of putting a shadow on CYBER which does not use mix-blend-mode but uses clip and takes an idea from [Add a drop shadow to transparent text with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750372/add-a-drop-shadow-to-transparent-text-with-css) it uses two divs with text Cyber, clipping one to overlay on one that has the shadow. You may want to play with the colors to get the effect you want.

```
body {
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
      background: url('https://freepik.cdnpk.net/img/category/vector.jpg') no-repeat;
      background-position: top center;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    .headline {
        font-size: 8rem;
        font-weight: 900;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        line-height: 6.8rem;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .shadow, .text {
      rdisplay: none;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      }
      .shadow {
      position: absolute;
      color: #ffffff;
        -webkit-text-stroke-width: 5px;
        -webkit-text-stroke-color: #ffcb06;
        text-shadow: #ffcb06 0px 0px 0px, #ffcb06 0px 0px 0px, #ffcb06 0px 0px 20px, #ffcb06 0px 0 20px;
    }
    .text {
        position: absolute;
          background: url('https://freepik.cdnpk.net/img/category/vector.jpg') no-repeat;
          background-position: top center;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
    }
    .monday {
        -webkit-text-stroke-width: 5px;
        -webkit-text-stroke-color: #00fdd5;
        text-shadow: #1efdf5 0px 0px 0px, #1efdf5 0px 0px 0px, #1efdf5 0px 0px 20px, #1efdf5 0px 0 20px;
        color: black;
        background: black;
        mix-blend-mode: screen;
    }
```

..........

This is the original answer which gave a look similar to the one in the image in the question, without shadow.

The suggestions of where to strip back to given here get you the word CYBER looking as in the picture in the question..

If you
remove the text shadow
change the color and background both to transparent
take out the mix-blend-mode
you get the CYBER outline in the correct color with its body being transparent so showing the colors behind.

```
.cyber {
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 5px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #ffcb06;
    color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Now you can start experimenting with text shadow and/or mix-blend-mode.You don't say what you want in the way of glow. Taking out the things suggested gets the effect like given in the picture in your question - no glow.

Note also that in using the mix-blend-node on the MONDAY you have some fairly similar colors. On the CYBER the yellowy color is in complete contrast. I expect you have done this already but it's worth looking at all the options in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) to see exactly what each does if you intend to go back to using that in the CYBER.

Comment: Your suggestion works completely fine, but removes the text shadow (outer glow). I need both word to have an outer glow. Perhaps that is difficult to see in the image, but you can see that text shadow (outer glow) in the fiddle.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. OK, what we need to do probably is use a different blend mode. The MONDAY sort of works because the colors of the background and the text are not much different whereas the yellow/orange is in contrast. I’ll experiment.